# Prevent cell selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, zooming

Is there a way to stop users (or even owners) selecting a cell or enter into the cell?

The reasons are two-fold

1. As owner of the sheet, I want to protect my own formula from being over-written, once I am finished with my sheet set-up. I can possibly use "protect sheet" functionality to achieve this. However, reason 2:
2. In desktop version on mobile devices, once a cell is clicked, Google sheets automatically zooms in to that cell at a ridiculous giant scale (even though I am using tablet, such zoom-in is completely unnecessary). When it happens you can't see anything else on the sheet except the selected cell and it is very difficult to use swipe/shrink it back. The desktop version opens fine with the right zoom-level I want the sheet to be. But it does the auto-zoom the moment any cell is clicked. Because I run script with control buttons on desktop version with no need to go into the cells, I'd really like to disable any cell selection so my sheet can stay at the right zoom level.

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets doesn't include any way to prevent cell selection.